# Are smartphone questions permitted on Super User?

Tags: discussion, support

The [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) states that [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com/) is for asking questions related to computer hardware and software.
Is asking iPhone or android questions allowed?

**EDIT:**  Maybe the real question is: do we consider an android phone or an iPhone a computer?

My [question](https://superuser.com/questions/20201/what-is-the-best-android-phone-available-on-the-market) has been asked!

**Edit 2:**
As a result of this and similar questions, the FAQ has been updated to read "and it is **not about** ... electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer"

Answer (score 10):

I'd say yes, since phones, especially smartphones nowadays, are essentially general-purpose computers and are subject to many of the same problems.

***Edit by Gnoupi***: since this post, [the situation has changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35733/update-the-superuser-faq). The [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) now clearly states that you should not ask questions about *"electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer"*.

Questions about electronic devices will be welcomed on this [Area 51 proposal site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), when it will launch.

Comment: Providing the question is discussing the programming of the devices?

Comment: Then it's probably better on stackoverflow than superuser.

Comment: Sorry Johannes for hacking into your answer, it was not actual anymore and used as reference.

Comment: The mentioned electronic-gadgets proposed site was closed.

Answer (score 6):

Only for extra-computery phones, and even then, it's best if the question is at least related to computer hardware or software.

Fex: "I want to transfer PDF files from my **COMPUTER** to the iPhone and read them on the iPhone at my leisure. How do I do that?"

Comment: the question i wanted to on superuser.com  was:  What android phone would you recommend & why? what say ye Jeff?  or are we looking at another stackoverflow forum fork?

Comment: that's already kind of a problem question on any SO-family site. "What {x} do you recommend and why?" is just a discussion.

Comment: it's a bit of a 'soft' question. but i can make it a 'hard' one.  What's the best android phone ? ;-)

Comment: You say at least related to computer hardware/sofware - but what about a problem with an iPhone app that's standalone? For example, "how do I do x in Mobile Safari."

Comment: @Jeff Was this one out of line? http://superuser.com/questions/20634/what-do-cell-phones-cell-network-devices-potentially-interfere-with-on-airplanes

Comment: @Jeff: and what about this one? http://superuser.com/questions/21789/is-sms-text-messaging-reliable-or-unreliable

Comment: I think phones should be totally fair game.  Most of them are very "computery".  Even if we're not discussing the computery features (email, web browsing).

Answer (score 0):

No, Superuser won't allow them unless the problem also involves a "real" computer.

You'd have to support one of these:

(Disclosure:  these are referral links)

**This is for general gadgets and gizmos:**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets?referrer=lu78is-6UwU1

**This one's for all things Apple, if you happen to mean an iphone:**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151/apple?referrer=LvSWwLbXk641

The former is a lot closer to a beta launch.

Answer (score -1):

Are smartphone questions permitted on Super User? This question is one that has been asked many times over a long period of years.

Meanwhile, technology has been advancing, and at an ever-increasing pace.

This particular question was posted here five years ago; our guidance has evolved a little since then. At present, we take the line that [Super User is for computer enthusiasts, and off-topic items include electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

The focus of our site is computers, and should remain so. But in 2015, it goes without saying that a smartphone *is* a computer. And here's the thing: not only is it a computer, but its significance in the world of personal computing has now exploded to an extent that led wired.com to [recently predict that in less than two years, we’ll be able to count on our smartphones to do all the tasks we currently need a desktop computer for](http://www.wired.com/2015/02/smartphone-only-computer).

With the smartphone now having such a significant role as a personal computer, we at Super User need to move with the times and accept that smartphones are now firmly within our sphere of interest.

Comment: We already have http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/. http://android.stackexchange.com/, http://apple.stackexchange.com/ for smartphone questions. Are you suggesting these sites are merged back into [su]?

Comment: Please read [Is a modern phone not a computer?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2878). I don't think that this answer is outdated.