# Chromecast Question On-topic?

Tags: support

Are questions about Chromecast and its use on-topic, like this [question](https://superuser.com/q/627901/179112), or do they belong on Android Enthusiasts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromecast falls into the 'electronics gadget' category, which would be [off-topic for Super User:](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> **electronic devices**, **media players**, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

Comment: If the electronic device is controlled by a computer, then it would on-topic. Wouldn't you say our Nexus' are computers as well?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra [we've had this discussion before](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2878/4377)

Comment: This perception of a computer is outdated. Should I have asked on Web Applications in stead?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I don't see how it would have fit on [webapps.se] - remember that it's not necessary for every question to be asked on [se]

Comment: I've went ahead and proposed a new SE site for Google products like the Chromecast: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115799/google

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second half of your question, there's no reason I can think of that the vast majority of Chromecast questions would belong on Android Enthusiasts.

The Chromecast devices don't run an Android OS (I think it's just the Chrome browser sitting on top of a generic Linux kernel, like the ChromeOS laptops) and they're operable from pretty much any modern OS (including iOS, Android, Windows, MacOS, and anything that can run Chrome) so I don't think there's anything Android specific with the Chromecast device.

If someone is hitting a specifically Android related problem streaming from an Android device to a Chromecast then that could be on-topic for AE, and obviously if and when there's an Android app released to control it, then questions about that app could be on-topic for AE. But you could say substitute "Android" for "iOS" or "Ubuntu" and so on all through that last sentence.

Comment: The OS is a modified Google TV.

Comment: @jacob I'm only going from the statements made at the announcement, Hugo Barra, Google vice president, said that Chromecast is "*running a simplified version of Chrome OS.*" I haven't heard anything to the contrary since. Nevertheless, it operates as "black box" gadget that's remote controlled by other devices and not like an Android device at all.