# Are questions about Smart TVs on-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

I want to ask about audio codec support of a (fairly recent) smart TV. However - this is somewhere between a "computer" and a plain-consumer-electronic device - even if it might actually be a pure matter of software rather than firmware.

Is this on or off topic?

Answer (score 3):

No. Smart TVs are not on topic here. They count as "electronic devices" or "media players" as per our [on-topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> and it is **not about** …
>
> electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

If you problem were specifically about connecting a computer and viewing a computer output on it then *that* could be on topic, but where the problem is entirely to do with the TV and has nothing to do with a computer connection then it is off topic.

The reasoning is similar to [why modern mobile phones are not classed as "computers"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2877/is-a-modern-phone-not-a-computer) in the topicality rules. There is nothing "standard" about the computer hardware used, and you are entirely at the whims of the manufacturer. There is no way to know the capabilities with 100% certainty. Software can change without any notice whatsoever. While Windows and Linux *can* change, the visibility of said changes is a lot higher and easier to determine.

You will need to consult your manufacturer.

If it is a mostly "standard" Android device then it might be on topic at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Fair enough. Problem is, the manufacturer doesn't seem to be overly forthcoming with contact information.

Comment: And sadly that is what makes them difficult to class as "conventional" computers. Sure they have processors and can "compute" things, and may even run some flavour of Linux or Android, but they lack any level of open-ness that makes them able to be *driven* as a normal computer. You get a basic UI and if it doesn't do what you want then you're basically out of luck. No one has any idea how to get to a useful command line or GUI interface except the manufacturer and they can make it completely disappear if it gets leaked. They have no reason to make anything useful publicly accessible.